# Using session in global to update user login counter in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, session, global-asax

Hallo,

I am relatively new in both asp and sql, but has created a website where users can log in and I want to save how many times each user has been logged in.

I want to use Global.asax to increment a field in my sql database each time a user goes in to the webpage, but can not get it to work.

I get no error message when I run the webpage, but the field in the database are not incremented.
Am I doing it all wrong?

Global.asax is empty while I typed the following in Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace HerningBrand
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //INCREMENT LoginCounter//
        //connect to the db
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.
                        ConnectionStrings["xxx_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Users SET LoginCounter
                        =LoginCounter+1 WHERE UserName='Test'", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //update where UserName is Test
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", "Test");

        using (conn)
        {                
            conn.Open();   //open the connection                
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   //send the query to increment the number
        }
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors are you getting? What exceptions? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have now edited my question.

Comment: Is that SQL statement correct? Seems to be missing a space after the SET keyword

Comment: It is changed now, it was a "copy-paste" error.  The SQL statement is tested in a .aspx page where it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

An ASP.NET session is separate from a user login. The session is initiated as soon as a user visits your site, before they've had a chance to login. If you're trying to test by logging in using a browser window that was already open, it won't work; you would need to close your browser (and possibly delete the cookie from your site) to get a new session.

Comment: Okay, this means that it is not the right way to count how many times a user has been logged in?
Obviously I can also count each time a user presses the login button, but then I do not get when the user selects "keep me logged in", is there a simple solution to the problem, so I get a reasonably accurate count of the times a user have logged in?

Comment: I think the "keep me logged in" doesn't work quite the way you expect. It actually just uses a permanent cookie instead of a temporary cookie to store the user's session, which means you can close your browser and reopen it, and you'll still be logged in, but your session will still expire after 30 minutes (or whatever your session timeout is set to). If you leave it unchecked, your session would not get carried over between separate browser sessions.

Comment: Think you're right, I have gotten it wrong.
Does this mean that I simply can count each time a user presses log in, because when a user has been 30 minutes (or whatever) away from the site, he has to press log in again? it explain why I've had trouble finding the answer when it is so simple :-)

Comment: @Soren Yes, that should be all you need to do

Answer (score -1):

`Session_Start` is called when a session starts.  Typically, this is once in the lifetime of a browser window.  Successive requests happen on the same session.

The function you're looking for is `Application_BeginRequest`.  This is called once for every page that is requested.

Comment: That would give the total number of pages a user has ever requested, including every time a page gets posted back, which is not even close to the number of times a user has logged into the site.